# Which parameters should be increased to indicate the variance from a function?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, statistics, variance

This is a function of `X` and `y`

```
X = np.random.rand(50,1)
y = ((X.T*X)**9 +X).reshape(-1)
```

How do you indicate if there's a variance in the data? What parameters control the variance and how can I increase it or decrease it? [where is the variance here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdNPF.png)

Can you please give me examples on the variance in the function ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.var(my_numpy_array,ddof=1)` in this case to calculate the variance of an array.

The parameter ddof comes from 'Delta Degrees of Freeedom', you can read more about them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics).

In your case, since y is calculated according to X, I would calculate the `np.var(y)` and check to see the result.

The threshold above which you consider your data to be varied enough depends on the case.